# Matrices Comparison,

Tags: linear-algebra

I found in two papers, in the field of nonlinear control, the following statement:

> $cI\leq Q$, where $c$ is a scalar, $I$ is the identity matrix and $Q$
>   is a symmetric, positive-definite but not necessarily diagonal matrix.

Can anyone please explain me the meaning of this statement?

Comment: That matrix $Q-cI$ is positive semi-definite?

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric matrices, then, by definition

$A \le B$ iff $\langle Ax,x \rangle \le \langle Bx,x \rangle$  for all $x$, where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is the inner product on $ \mathbb K^n$

Answer (score 0):

This inequality sign refers to [Loewner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order):

$A \leq B \ \iff B-A$ is symmetric semi-definite positive (SSDP)

In the present case, as remarked by @Zoran Loncarevic, it means that $Q-cI$ is SSDP, a property which is equivalent to:

> All eigenvalues of $Q$ are $\geq c$